# Basic webrtc example

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I just want to show same video in two video elements to simply understand how webrtc works. I wrote this:

```
    <video id="video1" autoplay></video>
    <video id="video2" autoplay></video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
        var video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
        var pc;

        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }, function(stream){
            pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(null);

            pc.addStream(stream);

            pc.onaddstream = function(e){
                alert('onaddstream');
                video2.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
            };

            pc.onicecandidate = function(e){
                alert('onicecandidate');
                if (!e || !e.candidate) return;
                pc.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
            };

            video1.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            pc.createOffer(function(description){
                pc.setRemoteDescription(description);
                pc.setLocalDescription(description);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But it does not work. Can you help?

Comment: You need a 'caller' and 'callee' RTCPeerConnection: you only have one. Try @Muaz Khan's example or the one at http://simpl.info/rtcpeerconnection.

Answer (score 6):

Try following demo:

```
<video id="peer2-to-peer1" autoplay controls style="width:40%;"></video>
<video id="peer1-to-peer2" autoplay controls style="width:40%;"></video>

<script>
 var mediaConstraints = {
     optional: [],
     mandatory: {
         OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
         OfferToReceiveVideo: true
     }
 };

 var offerer, answerer;
 var offererToAnswerer = document.getElementById('peer1-to-peer2');
 var answererToOfferer = document.getElementById('peer2-to-peer1');

 window.RTCPeerConnection = window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
 window.RTCSessionDescription = window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.RTCSessionDescription;
 window.RTCIceCandidate = window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.RTCIceCandidate;

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
 window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

 window.iceServers = {
     iceServers: [{
         url: 'stun:23.21.150.121'
     }]
 };

 /* offerer */

 function offererPeer(stream) {
     offerer = new RTCPeerConnection(window.iceServers);
     offerer.addStream(stream);

     offerer.onaddstream = function (event) {
         offererToAnswerer.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
         offererToAnswerer.play();
     };

     offerer.onicecandidate = function (event) {
         if (!event || !event.candidate) return;
         answerer.addIceCandidate(event.candidate);
     };

     offerer.createOffer(function (offer) {
         offerer.setLocalDescription(offer);
         answererPeer(offer, stream);
     }, onSdpError, mediaConstraints);
 }


 /* answerer */

 function answererPeer(offer, stream) {
     answerer = new RTCPeerConnection(window.iceServers);
     answerer.addStream(stream);

     answerer.onaddstream = function (event) {
         answererToOfferer.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
         answererToOfferer.play();
     };

     answerer.onicecandidate = function (event) {
         if (!event || !event.candidate) return;
         offerer.addIceCandidate(event.candidate);
     };

     answerer.setRemoteDescription(offer, onSdpSucces, onSdpError);
     answerer.createAnswer(function (answer) {
         answerer.setLocalDescription(answer);
         offerer.setRemoteDescription(answer, onSdpSucces, onSdpError);
     }, onSdpError, mediaConstraints);
 }



 function getUserMedia(callback) {
     navigator.getUserMedia({
         audio: true,
         video: true
     }, callback, onerror);

     function onerror(e) {
         console.error(e);
     }
 }

 getUserMedia(function (stream) {
     offererPeer(stream);
 });

 function onSdpError(e) {
     console.error('onSdpError', e);
 }

 function onSdpSucces() {
     console.log('onSdpSucces');
 }
</script>
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/demos/client-side.html).

Comment: The code works. but turning it to 2 html pages - one for video capture only, and another for video display only is horrible! Do you know where to find pure client/server, not p2p WebRTC JavaScript example. Or how to convert the code - it has no dependences but makes my mind crazy.

Comment: When I run this code, It shows my video on both video elements. I tried using with another machine in my network. when both machines load same page, again both video elements shows only the local video

Comment: @IsuruHerath WebRTC uses SDP protocol which follows offer/answer model. This model requires first peer to create offer and which needed to be shared with second peer. The process that we use to share one user's offer with other is named as "signaling". Signaling can happen either copy/pasting your code e.g. (https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc/) or via websocket, XHR [POST/GET], SIP, XMPP, etc. Demo in the "answer" merely targets single-page. No signaling medium is used here. That's why other peer can't be connected.

Comment: I found another answer on internet. But it requires to run separate wamp servers on two machines and each machine should log onto the web page on their local server. also I had to set the ip address on the remote machine where the websocket-server is running. But I need to log onto same web page in both machines and do connection without setting IP addresses. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please check this: http://muaz-khan.blogspot.com/2013/12/i-want-to-learn-webrtc.html See what kind of stuff is mandatory to connect two peers sitting behind different networks (e.g. signaling server + ICE server).