# Best way to stream array data to a client using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, streaming

I have a general question about best cases to get an array of data to constantly stream to a client uninterrupted as that array gets .push()s onto it?

I have looked at ajax requests and while that's fine, I figured pinging the server from the client a set interval to receive a stream of data is taxing plus it defeats the purpose of what I am trying to create, which is essentially a recreation of a chatroom.

I figured there is a better way to just load the data from the array into the client so it can just display it but the closest I have gotten to that is either adding another websocket layer (I already have a websocket running and it is gathering the data and pushing to this array) or using nodes stream ability which I have never used before.

Any general direction on this is a big help. I'm not really looking for perfection and I might just butcher some code together just to get something to work but I have been obsessed with getting the idea of this right for a few days now.

Thanks.

Comment: You could consider using webrtc to stream data.

Comment: I do not know what that is

Comment: It allows data, video, audio streaming between two peers. I suggest to read a bit more about it. 

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-beginners.html .

And checkout a simple example for video streaming, I believe it is not difficult to change it to be a data channel.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875605/basic-webrtc-example

. Also, I guess there are other good streaming methods out there so consider WebRTC just one possible option.